# Removing duplicates based on a "grouping"?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I currently have a one-to-many relationship with users and profile images that I need to change to be a one-to-one relationship.

I have a Users table, and then an ImageReference table that has a UserID.

What I need to do is for each User that has more than one associated ImageReference record, remove all ImageReference records EXCEPT for the most recent one.

So if a User has two image references, one with an ID of 100, and one with an ID of 150, I need to remove the one with the ID of 100.

Any idea on the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert all of the latest ImageReference rows (select max ID grouping by user ID) into a temporary table, then left join that table back on the ImageReference table delete those rows that do not join (where the ImageReference.ID is null).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```
SELECT  UserID,
        MAX(ImageRefID) LastUserImageID
FROM    UserImages
GROUP BY UserID
```

If this schema is to change to a 1-1, you should probably include the ImageRedID on the Users table.

Using Sql Server 2005, you can also remove them from the table directly.

Have a look at the following example.

```
DECLARE @UserImages TABLE(
        ImageRefID INT,
        UserID INT
)

INSERT INTO @UserImages SELECT 1, 1
INSERT INTO @UserImages SELECT 2, 2
INSERT INTO @UserImages SELECT 3, 1
INSERT INTO @UserImages SELECT 4, 1

;WITH Vals AS (
        SELECT  UserID,
                ImageRefID,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY ImageRefID DESC) RowID
        FROM    @UserImages
)
DELETE
FROM    Vals 
WHERE   RowID > 1

SELECT  *
FROM    @UserImages
```

Comment: Thanks, I gave the answer to the first guy, but this is really helpful for the future.

Comment: How the data is removed from the @UserImages table? I can see the earlier ImageRefID removed from the CTE named Vals.

Comment: It is actually deleting from the underlying table, not the CTE itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from ImageReference where ImgID in (
select ImgID
from ImageReference ir
  join (select UserID, max(ImgID) as MaxImgID
   from ImageReference
   group by UserID) MaxImgIDPerUser
 on ir.UserID = MaxImgIDPerUser.UserID
where ir.ImgID < MaxImgIDPerUser.MaxImgID)
```

Comment: Thanks man, this would probably be simpler but I used the first solution so I have to give the answer to him. :)